# Facebook like button is not counting like in account.

Tags: facebook

I implemented facebook like button. Its working fine and showing all feature and also working. When anybody clicks on like button. But when I check my likes on the facebook account they are not shown there. Is it because my site is now only locally available (localhost) or is there anything missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"is it because my site is now only locally available (localhost)"

yes; the URL you're liking should be a fully qualified URL which facebook's crawler can reach in order to get the metadata for that URL - see the like button docs for more information:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: Thanks Igy. That will help me.